# Spring Validation error not getting printed in my jsp

Tags: java, spring, forms, validation, jsp

I have a jsp as follows:

```
<form:form action="/SpringWebProject/login" method="post" modelAttribute="loginForm">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label id="username"><fmt:message key="login.username" />:</label>
</td> 
<td>
<form:input  path="username" /></td>
<td><form:errors path="username" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/login")   
public String verifyLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginForm loginForm,BindingResult bindingResult,LoginForm loginFrm)
{
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        System.out.println("here in error" + bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(0));
        return "login";
    }
    System.out.println("hello" +loginService);
    loginService.verifyLogin(loginForm);
```

My model object is LoginForm:

```
package com.neha.javabrains;



public class LoginForm {
public String username;
public String password;
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


}
```

Validator entry is:

```
@Override
    public void validate(Object loginClass, Errors errors) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("here in validator");
        LoginForm loginForm=(LoginForm)loginClass;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "username.empty","Username empty");
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
        Matcher matcher=p.matcher(loginForm.getUsername());
        boolean spclCharsPresent=matcher.find();
        if(spclCharsPresent)
        {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "SpecialCharactersPresent");
        }
    }
```

Here in my controller the Validator errors are printed but these errors are not showing on jsp.

I have all correct entries like modelAttribute and entry in property file but still no error is being printed.

Comment: How do you call your validator ?

Comment: @Mitchapp :  The validator is itself called by spring framework as i have added these annotations in my controller for binding validator:    `@Controller
public class LoginController {

public LoginService loginService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("loginFormValidator") 
public Validator validator;
@Autowired
public MessageSource messageSource;

@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
 binder.setValidator(validator);
}`

Comment: Remove `LoginForm loginFrm` from parameters list. Then bindingResult will bind first parameter `LoginForm loginForm` and it should be OK.

Comment: It worked Thanks a lot.